# how to add alpha channel (transparency) to background (not the front image) using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an RGB image and after doing processing identify an object in image (which is zeros and non-zero values for the object). The image shows a black background which I want to remove.

I have tried following two methods:

```
Method 1: 
    rgba_image = np.insert(
        rgb_image,
        3,   #position in the pixel value [ r, g, b, a <-index [3]  ]
        255, #change as per requirement  
        axis=2 #this is the depth where you are inserting this alpha channel into
    )

Method 2: 
    b, g, r = cv2.split(img_numpy)
    alpha = np.ones(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype) * 100 #creating a dummy alpha channel image.
    rgba_image = cv2.merge((b, g, r, alpha))
```

Both of these methods do actually change the transparency (but of the whole image). What I am looking for is to have transparent background with only showing the object

Could you please advise?

Comment: How do you define an object? Your code has no indicator of the said object.

Comment: First of all you need to define where is your object. Do you have a segmentation mask? do you have coordinates? a bounding box? After that, you should be able to extract that information from your image, operate the background then comeback to the original image.

Comment: Thank you Quang and Jairoar. yes i have the mask. i initialize the numpy array with zeros and apply the mask to get the object (say cat) in that array. when I imshow the image the background is black but I am looking to make it transparent. thanks.

Comment: in the above code rgb_image is the masked image (zeros for the background + object); semilarly in second example img_numpy is the masked image (zeros for the background + object)

Comment: You mean you want something like a .png image from your extracted object?

Comment: Post an example image to some free hosting service and put the URL here.

Comment: many thanks for your reply. yes. as an example suppose i have an image with cat. now after doing segmentation I got the mask. now i want to create a new png file with detected cat. i have created an numpy array (0 initialzed) and masked the input image to just get the cat in newly created array (this array will be written to new png file). since the image was initialized with 0 so I  see black background. I would rather want to see transparent which is why i started using alpha channel (working but also making my cat transparent). thank you.

Comment: fmw42: will do in a minute

Comment: please see the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NiHDa_XNQyoWJvVOKD4POAL97d9xTD30?usp=sharing (i have added 4 files: 1: original.jpg, 2:goal.png, without-alpha.png, and with-alpha.png)

Comment: You are making this unnecessarily complicated. Just do `RGBAimage = np.dstack((RGBimage,mask))`

Comment: Many thanks @MarkSetchell. You are right yesterday I spent whole day complicating this stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool! As you have working, tested code, you can write it up for others to see and grab the points by accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

@MarkSetchell helped me to resolve this. There was an additional bit in my case that i had the data in tensors so following code resolved this:

```
rgb_numpy = (image * 255).byte().cpu().numpy()

after this point the background is black

mask_alpha = (mask * 255).byte().cpu().numpy()

rgba_numpy = np.dstack((rgb_numpy,mask_alpha))
```

after this the mask layer is added which automatically highlight the area of the detected object and everything else goes transparent

Comment: Cool, well done and thank you for sharing back with the SO community.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, where I am trying to add an alpha channel but it shows a black background.  How do I remove the black background, could you possibly add to the script above?  Here is what I am trying to use: 
import cv2
# Read .png image in BGR format
img = cv2.imread(<input_image_filepath>)
# Convert from BGR to BGRA
bgra_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
cv2.imwrite(<new_image_filepath, bgra_img)